# What is wrong with this solution while solving JUICE on SPOJ?

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming

The problem is:

Jerry loses himself in the interesting game: Fruit Ninja. Fruit Ninja is a game of iPhone and iPad in which the players cut the fruits coming from the bottom of the screen and gain the bonus from cutting more than two fruits with a single slice. Once a fruit is cut, it breaks into small pieces and cannot be cut any more.

After months of training, he becomes pro of this game. Actually, he can cut all the fruits on the screen at any time. Jerry also has a bad habit that he has no willing to leave some fruits for the future cutting. In the other words, after Jerry cuts the fruits, all the fruits on the screen breaks and no one left. That is why all his friends call him Juice Extractor.

Now he only consider about the bonus, when he cuts more than two fruits, he can gain some bonus scores as same as the number of fruits he slice at that time. For example, if Jerry cuts 4 fruits with a single slice, he can get 4 scores from this slice.

After Jerry gets the fruit schedule, he knows the appearing time and the disappearing time for every single fruit. He can only cut a fruit into pieces between its appearing time and disappearing time inclusive. He wants to know the maximum possible bonus scores he can receive.

Input

There are several test cases; the first line of the input contains a single integer T, denoting the number of the test cases. (T <= 200)

For each test case, the first line contains an integer N, denoting the total number of fruits. (1 <= N <= 1000)

The next N lines, each line describe a fruit. For each line, there are two integers Xi and Yi, where Xi is the appearing time of the fruit and Yi is the disappearing time of this fruit. (0 <= Xi <= Yi <= 1000000000)

Output

For each test case, output a single integer denoting the maximum scores that Jerry could possibly gain. See the sample for further details.

Example

Input:
1
10
1 10
2 11
3 12
4 13
13 14
14 15
13 19
20 22
21 23
22 24

Output:
Case #1: 10

Here is the code :
It sorts the time intervals on basis of start time.dp[i] accounts for the time when ith fruit appears. We will be making a cut only when a fruit appears, as it will cover all the cases

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include<memory.h>
using namespace std;
struct node
{
    int x,y;
};
int cmp(node a,node b)
{
    if(a.x!=b.x)
    return a.x<b.x;
    return a.y<b.y;
}
int main()
{
    int test;
    cin>>test;
    int t=0;
    int dp[1002];
    while(test--)
    {
        t++;
        int n;
        cin>>n;
        vector<node> v(n);
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            int a,b;
            cin>>a>>b;
            v[i].x=a;
            v[i].y=b;
        }
        sort(v.begin(),v.end(),cmp);
        memset(dp,0,sizeof(dp));
        int mx=0;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            int id=100000,match=0;
            for(int j=0;j<=i;j++)
            {
                if(v[j].y>=v[i].x)
                {
                    id=min(id,j);
                    match++;
                }
            }
            for(int j=id;j<=i;j++)
            {
                if(match>2)
                dp[i+1]=max(dp[i+1],dp[j]+match);
                else
                dp[i+1]=max(dp[i+1],dp[j]);
                if(v[j].y>=v[i].x)
                match--;
            }

            dp[i+1]=max(dp[i+1],dp[i]);
            mx=max(mx,dp[i+1]);

        }
        cout<<"Case #"<<t<<": "<<mx<<"\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you should really include the actual question you want answered in the post, not only the title...

Comment: When you ask What is wrong with your code, you must specify the expected output and your output. And in this case, you must add a link to the question.

Comment: Added the question description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably wrong when there is some segments **having same start time**.

I run this test case with your code:

> 10
>
> 1 1
>
> 1 2
>
> 3 3
>
> 1 4
>
> 3 5
>
> 3 6
>
> 3 7
>
> 8 8
>
> 3 9
>
> 3 10

Your code output **10** but the answer is actually **9**

I have several WA because of this test case too,
and got AC after I handle this case...I will share my experience and please see if it is the same bug for you.

Using this test case, my code will output **10, I will explain quickly as follows:**

**Let dp(i) be the state that you have your last cut at i-th segment's start time**

Clearly, dp(i) = maximum (dp(j) + # of segments(after j)intersect with i-th segment) for all j < i

Physically , it means **you have the second last cut at j-th segment's start time** which is logical **except** if **j-th and i-th segment's start time is the same! Then it is not 2 different cut but the same cut!**

To handle this, **the correct way is choose the last segment of consecutive segments having same start time ONLY!**

(**Assuming the segment is sorted by start time already, the order below is the sorted order**)

Here is the bug, my program (maybe yours as well) gives the output 10 because (using 0-based)

DP(9) = DP(6) + # overlap segments in [7,9]

= 7 + 3 = 10!

If you look deeper, DP(6) = 7 is actually right, as it does not consider the segments afterwards. But **you should not use DP(6) to update any DP(X) for X>6!** as **the last segment having same start time (with 6-th segment) is the 8-th segment**

In short, if we use some DP state which is NOT the last one having the same start time with itself to update other DP states, something may go wrong.

My solution is that when I doing DP on the i-th segment, whenever I find some segments j having same start time with segment i (j < i), **I set DP(j) to negative infinity** so that it must not be optimal enough to update other states.

**EDITED: Accepted Code Added**
As required by OP, below is my code which is accpeted

```js
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#define pii pair<int,int>
#define x first
#define y second
#define INF 1LL<<28
using namespace std;

int T,n;
int dp[1005];
pii a[1005];
int main(){
 scanf("%d", &T);
 for(int qwe=1; qwe <= T; qwe++){
  scanf("%d", &n);
  for(int i=0; i<n;i++) scanf("%d%d", &a[i].x, &a[i].y);
  sort(a, a+n);
  memset(dp,0,sizeof(dp));
  
  for(int i=0; i<n;i++){
   int cnt = 0;
   for(int j=i-1; j>=0; j--){
    if(a[j].x == a[i].x){dp[j] = -INF; cnt++; continue;}
    cnt += (a[i].x >= a[j+1].x && a[i].x <= a[j+1].y);
    dp[i] = max(dp[i], dp[j] + (cnt>2? cnt:0));
   }
   
   cnt += (a[i].x >= a[0].x && a[i].x <= a[0].y);
   dp[i] = max(dp[i], (cnt>2? cnt:0));
  }
  printf("Case #%d: %d\n", qwe, dp[n-1]);
 }
 return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Yes only If i can tell my answer does help you